# No Windows Boot Option In Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

So I recently installed Ubuntu, but I didn't give it enough space. It started acting weird, so I restarted the computer. Afterwards, it just had a black screen after it started up. I tried the Windows Recovery Boot option, but it just brought me to the recovery. I tried using GParted on a live installation, but it didn't let me re-size the partition. Now I can't boot into anything. How can I get the Windows boot option back so I can re-size the partition?

Answer (score 0):

Download Boot Repair http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/
Burn it to a usb or a disk, and boot from it, and follow the instructions given by the boot-repair, and choose recommended repair :)

Comment: What tool should I use? Some operating systems only work with certain burners.

Comment: For windows, I highly recommend Rufus: https://rufus.akeo.ie/
For Ubuntu and it's relatives, in my experience the ISO burner never works. I've tried using WINE with Rufus, but it's unable to detect any type of drives. Linux Mint though, has a simple but working iso writer, pretty sure you can get it on Ubuntu with the right repository although I do not know what repository or what the package is called, sorry :(

Comment: I'm actually just going to reinstall Ubuntu. I didn't have any files on it, anyway.

Comment: If reinstalling Ubuntu doesn't work, drop a note @Fabby here: I've got another trick up my sleeve to drop-kick Windows...  ;-)

Comment: I figured out the answer. I must have deleted the Windows boot partition by accident.